# socket.io problem while connecting to room and errors appearing

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a problem on communicating with socketIO.

- First problem is that **I cannot communicate with another room**. And I don’t find the problem.
- Second problem is the following message: **index.js:83 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=PgUdXusyROLcKuieAAAI' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400**
- Third problem is similar to previous one and seems to fire at the same time: **VM845:1 POST http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MshuGZf&sid=fmIhjcRjS7yv-oeBAAAG 400 (Bad Request)**
- And fourth problem this one: **MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 warning listeners added.** -> For this one I could increase the limit, but I don’t think this is a good idea…

Here above you can find my code:

**app.js**

```
var server;

app.use((req, res, next) => {

  const io = require('socket.io')(server);
  var room;

  io.on('connect', function(socket){

    socket.on('room', function(room) {
      socket.join(room);
      console.log('Connected to room :' + room)
    });

    socket.on('chatMessage', function(msg){
      console.log('here :' + room + " - " + msg)
      socket.to(room).emit('chat message', msg);
    });

  });

  next();
});

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI)
  .then(result => {
    server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

**On client side:**
The values of room and message input in my client js code seems to work.

This line allows me on loading page to decide the room on which the socket has to connect:

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
  socket.emit('room', room);
});
```

This part seems to work beacause I get a console message saying that accounts are connected to the room.
While this one allows the client to send a message to a person that is in the room.  For this part I don't have any clue of why on app.js `console.log('here :' + room + " - " + msg)` is not triggered.

```
socket.emit('chatMessage', messageInput);
```

I hope the explanations are clear enought... I can post other things if necessary, but I think those are the essential parts.

Answer (score 0):

Remove socket-server implementation from the middle-ware as socket-server is created for every request sent to the server.
You should implement socket-server separately.

```
var server;

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI).then(result => {
    server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
    // socket server init
    socket_server(server);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

function socket_server(server) {
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);
    var room;
    io.on('connect', function (socket) {

        socket.on('room', function (room) {
            socket.join(room);
            console.log('Connected to room :' + room)
        });

        socket.on('chatMessage', function (msg) {
            console.log('here :' + room + " - " + msg)
            socket.to(room).emit('chat message', msg);
        });

    });
}
```

I would suggest you to go through [socket-io docs](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express)  .